# Converting html entities to characters in Android

Tags: android, html, entity

I am parsing JSON data and using it in Android textview.

And I am getting < instead of <, etc.

I tried with

```
Html.fromHtml("ur text here");
```

but this is deprecated and Android studio is not allowing me to use it.

As I saw in google documentation i need to use 2 parameters, from which other is some int Flag, and I don't know how to use it.

Comment: *but this is deprecated* it is, starting from android n. *Android studio is not allowing me to use it.* That's not true.

Comment: Either continue using `fromHtml(String)`, or on API Level 24+ devices switch to `fromHtml(String, int)`, [passing in `FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY` as the flag](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY). And, as Blackbelt points out, please edit your question to explain, in detail, what "is not allowing me to use it" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    Html.fromHtml("ur text here",Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
} else {
    Html.fromHtml("ur text here");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY) as the second parameter.